# Move pictures, sorted by Date-taken?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I'm trying to find an automated solution in a `bat` file, via `robocopy` or just simple `move` and `mkdir` commands.

I would like to move pictures based on their Date parameter into a new folder, whose filename is the date of the picture taken.

This is what I have so far

```
 @echo off
    set "src=D:\Photos\365\base"
    set "dest=D:\Photos\365\base"
    for %%F in ("%src%\*") do (
      for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%A in ("%%~tF") do (
        if not exist "%dest%\%%C_%%A" mkdir "%dest%\%%C_%%A"
        move "%%~fF" "%dest%\%%C_%%A"
      )
    )
```

But that takes the date **modified**. 
How could I call the Date taken parameter in `CMD`?

I looked through the docs for robocopy parameters, but that wasn't in it.

Comment: Native Windows `cmd` commands and also `robocopy` cannot read the date-taken property from an image file (like EXIF or IPTC data), so you need some external (command line) tool for that; in case you are satisfied with the creation date or the last modification date which are provided by the file system and understood by `cmd`, just let us know...

Comment: date taken is not a system property. I would recommend to create a python script to perform that task (parse the image and retrieve the proper date from data file not from file meta info)

Comment: Even PowerShell (which is built in) can do this.

Comment: You might be interested in this solution. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Rename-picture-files-with-97738191